5GHz channels blocked until iw scan completed
On my complex ath10 card on a debian 11 box after a clean boot
iw list shows
Frequencies:

5180 MHz [36] (30.0 dBm) (no IR)
5200 MHz [40] (30.0 dBm) (no IR)
5220 MHz [44] (30.0 dBm) (no IR)
5240 MHz [48] (30.0 dBm) (no IR)
5260 MHz [52] (30.0 dBm) (no IR, radar detection)
DFS state: usable (for 358 sec)
DFS CAC time: 60000 ms
5280 MHz [56] (30.0 dBm) (no IR, radar detection)
DFS state: usable (for 358 sec)
DFS CAC time: 60000 ms
5300 MHz [60] (30.0 dBm) (no IR, radar detection)
DFS state: usable (for 358 sec)
DFS CAC time: 60000 ms
5320 MHz [64] (30.0 dBm) (no IR, radar detection)
DFS state: usable (for 358 sec)
DFS CAC time: 60000 ms
5500 MHz [100] (disabled)
5520 MHz [104] (disabled)
5540 MHz [108] (disabled)
5560 MHz [112] (disabled)
5580 MHz [116] (disabled)
5600 MHz [120] (disabled)
5620 MHz [124] (disabled)
5640 MHz [128] (disabled)
5660 MHz [132] (disabled)
5680 MHz [136] (disabled)
5700 MHz [140] (disabled)
5720 MHz [144] (disabled)
5745 MHz [149] (30.0 dBm) (no IR)
5765 MHz [153] (30.0 dBm) (no IR)
5785 MHz [157] (30.0 dBm) (no IR)
5805 MHz [161] (30.0 dBm) (no IR)
5825 MHz [165] (30.0 dBm) (no IR)
5845 MHz [169] (30.0 dBm) (no IR)
5865 MHz [173] (disabled)

however if i do
iw dev wlan0 scan
the appropriate frequencies are now available.
Frequencies:

5180 MHz [36] (30.0 dBm)
5200 MHz [40] (30.0 dBm)
5220 MHz [44] (30.0 dBm)
5240 MHz [48] (30.0 dBm)
5260 MHz [52] (30.0 dBm) (no IR, radar detection)
5280 MHz [56] (30.0 dBm) (no IR, radar detection)
5300 MHz [60] (30.0 dBm) (no IR, radar detection)
5320 MHz [64] (30.0 dBm) (no IR, radar detection)
5500 MHz [100] (disabled)
5520 MHz [104] (disabled)
5540 MHz [108] (disabled)
5560 MHz [112] (disabled)
5580 MHz [116] (disabled)
5600 MHz [120] (disabled)
5620 MHz [124] (disabled)
5640 MHz [128] (disabled)
5660 MHz [132] (disabled)
5680 MHz [136] (disabled)
5700 MHz [140] (disabled)
5720 MHz [144] (disabled)
5745 MHz [149] (30.0 dBm)
5765 MHz [153] (30.0 dBm) (no IR)
5785 MHz [157] (30.0 dBm) (no IR)
5805 MHz [161] (30.0 dBm) (no IR)
5825 MHz [165] (30.0 dBm) (no IR)
5845 MHz [169] (30.0 dBm) (no IR)
5865 MHz [173] (disabled)

and i'm able to bring up wifi via hosapd. However if i stop hostapd and do another scan then the frequencies are blocked again. What is the cause of channels being blocked before the scan? I've tried setting country via iw reg but that also fails to work.

It looks like there may be two things going on here:

A world-mode card that isn't sure if you're in a locale that allows any 5GHz activity.
Radar/DFS channels that can't be used until a CAC has cleared.

World-mode card
Most Wi-Fi cards are pre-programmed for a default regulatory locale which determined which channels they'll let themselves use by default. But most are also allowed to switch to other regulatory locales on the fly if they see APs around them advertising a different locale. So your card, when first powered on, seems to think it can't transmit on any 5GHz frequency. But after a scan it probably saw APs advertising a certain country code in their beacons, and so your card switched to that locale, allowing it to use those channels.
DFS/Radar Channels
Some 5GHz channels overlap with frequencies used by legacy radar systems. To avoid interfering with radar, Wi-Fi devices are required to listen silently for radar energy pulses on the channel for 60 seconds before beginning to use the channel. This is known as a "Channel Availability Check" or "CAC". If, during the CAC period or anytime afterwards, you hear a radar energy pulse on the channel, you must immediately switch to a different channel picked at random. This behavior is known as "Dynamic Frequency Selection" or "DFS". The channels that require this behavior are called "DFS channels" or "radar channels".
BUT! If, while listening on the channel, you hear a beacon from an AP that's already on the channel, you're allowed to assume that the other AP has already done a CAC and found the channel to be free of radar, so you're allowed to start transmitting on it as soon as you hear someone else's beacon on it.
The output you showed suggests to me that your software started out warning you that it may need to do a 60 second CAC on any of the DFS channels before it can use any of them, but after you did a scan it probably heard other APs' beacons on those channels so it marked them as available without requiring a CAC first.

Does the same apply to the non-DFS channels 36-48 that the driver initially marks as "no-IR"?

@grawity_u1686 Oh, thanks, I'd overlooked that. I've updated my Answer to cover it.
